# can we show badge without APNS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, apple-push-notifications, badge

I want to simulate push notification without using apple's push notification server, so I want to know can I show badge also if yes which API or Objective-C code I have use to show badge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:<n>]`. See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW55).

Answer (score 1):

We can use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:<n>]` to show the badge with out APNS.

If we want to reset the previous badge while application is restarted ,we can use this
 `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];`